# UnicodeEncodeError when writing CSV file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, csv

I'm using the following script to convert my XML products to CSV

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('ItemCatDesc2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


columns = ['Name'] + [value.attrib.get('AttributeID') for value in tree.findall('.//Product//Value')]

with open('ItemCatDesc2.csv', 'w') as ofile:
    ofile = csv.DictWriter(ofile, set(columns))
    ofile.writeheader()
    for product in tree.findall('.//Product'):
        d = {value.attrib.get('AttributeID') : value.text
             for value in product.findall('.//Values/Value')}
        d['Name'] = product.findtext('Name')
        print d
        ofile.writerow(d)
```

When I run the script:

```
python convert.py ItemCatDesc2.xml > ItemCatDesc2.csv
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 21, in <module>
    ofile.writerow(d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbd' in position 362: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The XML I'm converting is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried that, same result.
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbd' in position 362: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: `# -*- coding:` is only used when the **source code** contains non-ascii, which is not the case here